# How Get Parent Field in Attachment?

Tags: apex, soql, attachment, dynamic-soql, servicecloud

Please Help me...

Account sObject is Parent of Attachment. Now I want to bring Read-only Field Custom field (isReadOnly__c).

```
SELECT Id, Name, Account.isReadOnly__c FROM Attachment
```

How It Gets ?

Thanks in Advance

Manu

Answer (score 5):

There is a feature you can use in your own orgs, via a pilot feature, called [TYPEOF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm), that allows you to get a parent field for a concrete type.

That query looks like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, 
  TYPEOF Parent WHEN Account THEN isReadOnly__c END
FROM Attachment
```

To enable this feature, you currently need to contact Support. Certain limitations may apply to this feature.

Comment: when printing the query or runing it in the dev console, the fields in this case isReadOnly__c doesnt show up in the result, how can you access that record ".account.isreadonly__c" value?

Comment: @manza The developer console does not support TYPEOF (part of the "limitations" surrounding this feature right now). Try using [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) to see a working example.

Comment: @sfdxfox thank you, that have sense i read the docs, but i probably miss that part of developer console mot been supported,

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it like that.

What you need to do is gather all your attachment records and store the parentID

Then you need to create a collection of ParentIDs to Records.

Now you can manipulate them.

For Example:

```
Map<ID,Account> accountMap = New Map<ID,Account>();
Attachment[] files = [Select ID, ParentID From Attachment]; //You will need to filter as appropriate

for(Attachment file : files){
     if(file.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Account.SobjectType)
          accountmap.put(file.ParentID,null);
}

accountMap = New Map<ID<Account>([Select ReadOnly__c From Account Where ID IN :accountMap.keySet()];
```

Now you have a map of accounts and can cycle through the attachments and get the appropriate account record and check readOnly__c

Comment: `if(file.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Account.SobjectType)` avoids using describes unnecessarily.